# Export highchartgraph with tooltips and labels

Tags: graph, highcharts, tooltip, angular-highcharts

I am trying to export the highcharts graphs as pdf. It seems to be exporting correctly but the tooltips or any kind of labelings are missing.

I have a combination of 2 graphs circular and linear progress bars which shows the name and progress of each series. When I check on the graph I can see everything perfectly but once I convert the same graph to pdf I want to see all its tooltips and plottings so the user can identify the values from the pdf.

Tooltip defines as

```
 tooltip: {
useHTML: true,
shared: true,
formatter: function() {
  return '<i>' + this.points[0].key + '</i>: <b>' + Math.round(this.points[0].percentage) + '%</b>';
}
```

},

Here is the [code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/Athulya_Ratheesh/bs7dLj28/17/) for the graphs. It has a linear and a circular graph as shown in the picture below.

[image]

In the above, I need to add markings which represents what data and values.

Answer (score 0):

You can define export settings in `exporting.chartOptions` and use `series.dataLabels` to achieve that. This is the basic example, but `dataLabels` can be freely stylized:

```
  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          dataLabels: {
            style: {
              textOutline: false
            },
            enabled: true,
            align: 'right',
            formatter: function() {
              if (this.series.name !== 'background filler') {
                return '<i>' + this.key + '</i>: <b>' + Math.round(this.percentage) + '%</b>';
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o3Lyp8rn/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions

---

**EDIT:**

In the case of solidgauge series, you will need to render the labels using Highchart SVG Renderer. Here is the example:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
    events: {
      render() {
        this.series.forEach(series => {
          if (!series.label) {
            series.label = this.renderer
              .label(series.data[0].y.toString(), 0, 0, 'rect', 0, 0, true, true)
              .css({
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '10px'
              })
              .add(this.series[1].group);
          }
          series.label.translate(
            this.chartWidth / 2 - series.label.width - this.plotLeft / 2,
            this.plotHeight / 2 + series.points[0].shapeArgs.innerR + this.plotTop / 2
          );
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8n9kfz0c/

Comment: It doesnt works for me in case of solidgauge charts. Label shows under the colored area.

Comment: Apologize, I referred only to the code snipped. When it comes to the solid gauge, labels can be rendered as in the following thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54027956/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-custom-label-position-on-a-highcharts-activity-gauge

Comment: The above referred example is entirely returns a different solution than I am expecting, I need to just show the value in the same circle itself. Like 30%, 20% etc...

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your requirement. Could you please share the image, which shows where the labels should be put?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i3TiKVaW1lFzX-9DjzfbwIrw841jrXaV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, thank you for providing the image. As I mentioned in your other thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75968014/solidgauge-labels-and-legends-not-reflectings-series-color/75994131?noredirect=1#comment134047548_75994131) it can be done by rendering the labels. I updated my ansewer. Regards!